# RoR deploy fails sp_helptext:There is no text for object X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

Yesterday we could no longer deploy our RoR application. This is what we found in the log: (changed the real table name to "table_name")

```
ERROR -- : TinyTds::Error: There is no text for object 'table_name'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC sp_helptext [table_name]'
```

When we executed this statement on the database, we got:

```
execute sp_helptext table_name

Msg 15197, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 107
There is no text for object 'table_name'.
```

We found the reason for it: we had both a table and a view with the same name in the SQL Server 2012 database, but in a different schema: the table was named dbo.table_name and the view dm.table_name. This somehow provoked ActiveRecord to run sp_helptext for that table (or view? ActiveRecord does not pass the schema name too, as it should. Tssk, tssk).

The solution/workaround was to rename the views to something else like dm.table_name_

We could not google the solution. It took some time to figure this out. Hope this post will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Well, for one, [stop leaving out the schema](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx), especially when you are actively using multiple different schemas...

Comment: Good point. That's exactly how we feel about it. How can we force ActiveRecord to always add the schema?

Comment: Sorry, don't know, don't use ActiveRecord (or RoR at all). How does it know about `table_name`? Is this referenced in a query you provided that doesn't have the schema attached?

Comment: ActiveRecord seems to scan the database for all its tables (maybe views too), and query the database to know the structure of those tables (columns, data type, ...). I'm the db guy, I only have a shallow knowledge of RoR. The developers don't know how to force ActiveRecord to always include the schema name.

Comment: Sounds like a serious flaw to me.